# Control over scheduling/placement in Apache Storm

Tags: apache-storm

I am running a wordcount topology in a Storm cluster composed on 2 nodes. One node is the Master node (with Nimbus, UI and Logviewer) and both of then are Supervisor with 1 Worker each. In other words, my Master node is also a Supervisor, and the second node is only a Supervisor. As I said, there is 1 Worker per Supervisor.

The topology I am using is configured so that it is using these 2 Workers (`setNumWorkers(2)`). In details, the topology has 1 Spout with 2 threads, 1 *split* Bolt and 1 *count* Bolt. When I deploy the topology with the default scheduler, the first Supervisor has 1 Spout thread and the *split* Bolt, and the second Supervisor has 1 Spout thread and the *count* Bolt.

Given this context, how can I control the placement of operators (Spout/Bolt) between these 2 Workers? For research purpose, I need to have some control over the placement of these operators between nodes. However, the mechanism seems to be transparent within Storm and such a control is not available for the end-user.

I hope my question is clear enough. Feel free to ask for additional details. I am aware that I may need to dig into Storm's source code and recompile. That's fine. I am looking for a starting point and advices on how to proceed.

The version of Storm I am using is 2.1.0.

Answer (score 1):

Scheduling is handled by a pluggable scheduler in Storm. See the documentation at http://storm.apache.org/releases/2.1.0/Storm-Scheduler.html.

You may want to look at the `DefaultScheduler` for reference https://github.com/apache/storm/blob/v2.1.0/storm-server/src/main/java/org/apache/storm/scheduler/DefaultScheduler.java. This is the default scheduler used by Storm, and has a bit of handling for banning "bad" workers from the assignment, but otherwise largely just does round robin assignment.

If you don't want to implement a cluster-wide scheduler, you might be able to set your cluster to use the [ResourceAwareScheduler](http://storm.apache.org/releases/2.1.0/Resource_Aware_Scheduler_overview.html#Enhancements-on-original-DefaultResourceAwareStrategy), and use a topology-level scheduling strategy instead. You would set this by setting `config.setTopologyStrategy(YourStrategyHere.class)` when you submit your topology. You will want to implement this interface https://github.com/apache/storm/blob/e909b3d604367e7c47c3bbf3ec8e7f6b672ff778/storm-server/src/main/java/org/apache/storm/scheduler/resource/strategies/scheduling/IStrategy.java#L43 and you can find an example implementation at https://github.com/apache/storm/blob/c427119f24bc0b14f81706ab4ad03404aa85aede/storm-server/src/main/java/org/apache/storm/scheduler/resource/strategies/scheduling/DefaultResourceAwareStrategy.java

Edit: If you implement either an `IStrategy` or `IScheduler`, they need to go in a jar that you put in `storm/lib` on the Nimbus machine. The strategy or scheduler needs to be on the classpath of the Nimbus process.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I've tried the following : I have a `MyScheduler` class within the starter package (next to `WordCountTopology`). My scheduler is empty and just doing a `LOG.info()`. In the topology I call `conf.setTopologyStrategy("org.apache.storm.starter.MyScheduler");` and I'm able to see this info in the execution logs. However, I'm not able to see any logs from `MyScheduler`. Is it possible that Storm rolls back on `EvenScheduler`? Where should I see the scheduler's logs?

Comment: Just to be clear, your `MyScheduler` implements the IStrategy interface, right? I would expect the log to show up in the Nimbus log (/logs/nimbus.log in your storm directory)

Comment: No, it implements the `IScheduler` interface. I took inspiration from `EvenScheduler` which was a mistake. I'll change that and come back with an update during the day! Thanks.

Comment: So far, what I understood is that Storm can use different schedulers and that we don't need to implement our own scheduler but rather a _strategy_ on top of the `ResourceAwareScheduler`. Changing strategy used by a topology seems not to be taken into account if scheduler is not changed (in _storm.conf_ by setting `storm.scheduler`). Now that everything is configured, it seems my `MySchedulerStrategy` class is not found : (in _nimbus.log_) `java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.storm.starter.MySchedulerStrategy`. Do you have any idea on what I'm doing wrong?